# Compare regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to compare following string by Regular Expression. I have surf lot of time but unable to get it's pattern.

```
         string str = "Full Name: Atif Mahmood"
                    + "ID Number: 12345678901"
                    + "Mobile Number: +921234567890";
```

In above string

```
Full Name:

ID Number:

Mobile Number:
```

are necessary with sequence and there should be any string after these constants.

Comment: I still dont get it; do you want a regular expression that recognizes your declared `string str`?

Comment: For clarification: you want to extract these parts of the string and compare them with another string?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? You don't seem to be comparing anything. Do you mean you want to extract the text after `Full Name:`, `ID Number:` and `Mobile Number:`?

Comment: Also note that in your actual string there are no line breaks or spaces between the string parts. If you print it you'd get `MahmoodID` and `...901Mobile`.

Comment: Yes I want to get regular expression for string str

Comment: Like `^Full Name:.*ID Number:.*Mobile Number:.*$`?

Comment: _are necessary with sequence and there should be any string after these constants_ translates to: are required in this sequence and there should be some content between them. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var regex = "Full Name:(.*)ID Number:(.*)Mobile Number:(.*)";
var match = Regex.Match(string, regex);
```

match.Groups[1] will contain the name, [2] will contain the ID number, etc. (Groups[0] is the whole match group, so counting each match starts at 1)

This probably needs some bullet proofing, but you get the idea?

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to check that the string follows the pattern you stated, this expression should do it:

```
const string expression = "Full Name:.*ID Number:.*Mobile Number:.*";
bool correct = Regex.IsMatch(str, expression);
```

Comment: You probably want to add anchors. Otherwise anything would be allowed in front of `Full Name:`

Comment: @m.buettner - True, depending on the rules for the matching. The specification is somewhat vague.